# Add to cart quantity logic RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, if-statement, model, controller

I have a method called add_to_cart created that is being called each time a user adds a product to their cart - the method then checks to see if the item already exists and if it does it increases the quantity by +1.

The issue I am having is that I am unsure how to call my Items 'create' action (in Items controller) from my model if a product does not already exist in the cart.

I think I could use Item.create(...) but I would rather just call the create action that already exists in my Items controller.

Currently I have:

Products#Index View

```
 ...
 <%= button_to "Add to Cart", add_to_cart_path(:product_id => product), :method => :post %>
 ...
```

Routes

```
 ...
 post '/add_to_cart/:product_id' => 'carts#add_to_cart', :as => 'add_to_cart'
 ...
```

Carts Controller

```
 class CartsController < ApplicationController

 def show
   @cart = current_cart
 end

 def add_to_cart
   current_cart.add_item(params[:product_id])
   redirect_to cart_path(current_cart.id)
 end

 end
```

Cart Model

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :items

def add_item(product_id)
        item = items.where('product_id = ?', product_id).first
    if item
        # increase the quantity of product in cart
        item.quantity + 1
        save
    else
        save # "THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO CALL ITEMS CONTROLLER CREATE"
    end
end
```

Items Controller

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController

def create
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @item = Item.create!(:cart => current_cart, :product => @product, :quantity => 1, :unit_price => @product.price)
    redirect_to cart_path(current_cart.id)
end

end
```

Any help on how I can achieve this redirect to my create action would really be much appreciated! :)

Comment: I don't think it is a MVC way to call a method in controller from a model. If some logic would be shared among controllers, the logic should be in models. "Fat models, skinny controllers."

Comment: @Yanhao Thanks so much for your reply. Would you recommend using an `Item.create` action in the model then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Cart` model can not call controller methods, and shouldn't need to.

Your method should look like this:

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items

  def add_item(product_id)
    item = items.find_or_create_by_product_id(product_id)
    item.quantity += 1
    item.save
  end
end
```

Then your `CartsController`.`add_item` method can redirect the user to where they should be.